# Accesing facebook event cover image with direct url is giving errors. Unable to Import

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a php script which fetches facebook events details including their cover image as well.

the cover image has got some params after the file extension and if I try to remove it so that I can download the cover image. it gives the following error :

**

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.4d4bf6d8.1409292400.53580bb6
```

**

**the sample url for testing** :

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10615623_712661278807208_4151858164785468114_n.jpg?oh=83c0a40f1b57b3466839bbbe17d50ab6&oe=545D09E6&**gda**=1417065942_9ac0a46e6667825a737edd93630685c5](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10615623_712661278807208_4151858164785468114_n.jpg?oh=83c0a40f1b57b3466839bbbe17d50ab6&oe=545D09E6&__gda__=1417065942_9ac0a46e6667825a737edd93630685c5)

**the image is not accessible if you try to access with**

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10615623_712661278807208_4151858164785468114_n.jpg

any idea how to go about it ?

PS : The event is not private.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using curl. This is what I did, and it worked for the image URL (with params) you gave:

`

```
<?php
$url = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10615623_712661278807208_4151858164785468114_n.jpg?oh=83c0a40f1b57b3466839bbbe17d50ab6&oe=545D09E6&__gda__=1417065942_9ac0a46e6667825a737edd93630685c5";
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
file_put_contents("eventImageID.jpg", $result);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($handle);
?>
```

`

I hope that works for you.

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you'd want to do it the way you described. It's much more natural to use the Graph API to request the cover photo (given that you know the `event_id`, by using

```
/{event-id}/picture
```

as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/picture This will return the actual picture. If you just want the `url` of it, append `redirect=false` to the request. You need a User Access Token.

Sample request:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1529936507237312%2Fpicture%3Fredirect%3Dfalse&version=v2.1

Comment: there is a diff between cover & image that's why facebook api has two different methods. Please try picture & cover methods on an event yourself and see the difference

Comment: I think we're both wrong upon closer look. There's no `/{event_id}/cover` edge, and even if https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/picture states *"An event's cover photo."*, it's in face the Event's profile picture. I filed a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/346595455515107/

Comment: actually its `/{event_id}/?fields=cover`

Comment: Well, I know that. Reading is possible, but as a general thing, you can't publish to a field. As you want to read only, using `/{event_id}/?fields=cover` should be fine